# Выходит ошибка при написании функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Господа, помогите плз, написал такую штуку:

```
import re
from wiki_req import get_topic_page

def get_topic_text (topic):
    html_content = get_topic_page(topic)
    words = re.findall("[а-яА-Я\-]+", html_content)
    text = " ".join(words)
    return text

print(get_topic_text ("Москва"))
```

а он мне выдает такое

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/helloworld/ООП/ООП4/index.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(get_topic_text ("Москва"))
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/helloworld/ООП/ООП4/index.py", line 6, in get_topic_text
    words = re.findall("[а-яА-Я\-]+", html_content)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Помогите пожалуйста

вот тут исходный сам файл wiki_req

```
from requests import get
"""https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Россия"""

def get_link(topic):
    link = "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + topic
    return link

def get_topic_page (topic):
    link = get_link(topic)
    html_content = get(link).text
    with open("new.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(html_content)
    return True

print(get_topic_page ("биржа"))
```

Comment: Библиотека wiki_req не гуглится, так что придется тебе помогать себе самому. Предположу, что get_topic_page возвращает не текст, а словарь, список или какой другой тип данных.

Comment: @КириллМаликов Тогда приведите, пожалуйста, объект, который возвращает эта функция (или исходный код функции). _P. S.: Человека можно упомянуть с помощью символа `@`, так ему придёт уведомление._

Comment: @Эникейщик wiki_req это тоже питоновский файл, который лежит рядом с основным файлом в котором есть функция get_topic_page

Comment: @nomnoms12 Отредоктировал сам вопрос, там добавил исходный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `get_topic_page` из модуля `wiki_req` возвращает значение типа `bool`, в Вашем случае — `True`.

Вы пытаетесь использовать значение `True` как строку (или файл) для поиска по регулярному выражению, поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Ваша инструкция с подставленным значением не имеет смысла, посмотрите:

```py
words = re.findall("[а-яА-Я\-]+", True)  # Возникнет ошибка!
```

---

Скорее всего, ошибка как раз в модуле `wiki_req`, где Вы должны возвращать `HTML`-код, вместо булевого значения:

```py
def get_topic_page (topic):
    link = get_link(topic)
    html_content = get(link).text
    with open("new.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(html_content)
    return html_content
```

---

Альтернативным решением может стать чтение из файла, в который функция `get_topic_page` записала результат:

```py
def get_topic_text (topic):
    get_topic_page(topic)
    with open('new.html', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        html_content = f.read()

    words = re.findall("[а-яА-Я\-]+", html_content)
    text = " ".join(words)
    return text
```

Comment: Работает, огромное спасибо)))

Comment: которое, альтернативное решение